# Running Splash on Docker Toolbox with Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, docker, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am trying to install and run splash on using Windows 10 Home. I have installed docker toolbox, as on windows 10 Home you can't install docker. Then in command prompt when I type

```
docker pull scrapinghub/splash
```

I get the error

```
error during connect: Post http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.40/images/create?fromImage=scrapinghub%2Fsplash&tag=latest: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.
```

One interesting thing I noticed was that if I run Docker Quickstart Terminal I can install splash with the command

```
docker pull scrapinghub/splash
```

and then using the command

```
docker run -p 5023:5023 -p 8050:8050 -p 8051:8051 scrapinghub/splash
```

it gives me

server listening on http://0.0.0.0:8050

But then when I paste http://0.0.0.0:8050 into Chrome it gives me "This site can't be reached."

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So 1st error clearly says that your Docker container is not running, so your pull command fails

You can check by running any docker command maybe try this

```
docker --version
```

For your 2nd query, you need to use Docker IP, to access the application

You can try `docker-machine ip` to see, on what IP docker is running (Assuming docker-machine is installed)

Generally, on windows Docker IP is `192.168.99.100`

Try these 2

```
192.168.99.100:8050
```

or

```
localhost:8050
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help MyTwoCents, using your solution I was able to solve my second problem and am now able to connect properly. But onto the first one again what do I do to start the docker container running? I have read you start a program called dockercli, but that seems to be only on Docker and not Docker Toolbox?

Comment: Refer this https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/  Check if Virtual box is running. Also when you start Docker Toolbox if all is well you will see Docker running on IP :  xxxxxxxxxx some IP.